# Formatting numbers with commas in D3

Tags: string, formatting, d3.js

When I create a chart with D3 the axis labels have commas in them to delimit thousands, millions, etc.

Is there a D3 function that I can call passing it a number and getting back a string formatted with commas like used in the axis?  It would be the equivalent of this C#: `x.ToString("0,000")`.

I know there exist libraries to do formatting like this, but I'd like to avoid including additional libraries.  I'm using D3 already, so if there is an API in there I can use that would be great.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A quick search in the documentation found it:

```
format = d3.format("0,000");
formattedX = format(x);
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Formatting#wiki-d3_format

Comment: How could this get 21 upvotes and be the accepted answer? It is wrong, the format specifier is invalid. Following the link to the docs one can easily see that there must not be a digit behind the comma. It happens to work by chance because there is a comma in the string. That, eventually, is the only character needed to enable grouping.

Answer (score 20):

The syntax for doing this has become more strictly enforced in d3 v4 but looks like:

```
format = d3.format(",");
formattedX = format(x);
```

[D3 formatting docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-format/blob/master/README.md#format)

Comment: It hasn't changed from v3 to v4. v4 is just a bit more picky complaining about the wrong specifier whereas v3 just kept on going interpreting what it could grasp. The self-answer by MattD is just missing the point. See my comment on that answer. All you need to enable grouping is `d3.format(",")`. You won't even need the final `"d"` character. Please adjust your answer accordingly and, maybe, add a link to the docs for reference.

Answer (score 8):

To save you from reading @altocumulus' comments, this is the correct answer:

`let format = d3.format(',');
let formattedX = format(x);`

From [the docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format):

> The comma (`,`) option enables the use of a group separator, such as a comma for thousands.

(@altocumulus gets all the credit.)

Comment: `var x = d3.format("$,.2f")(myVal); ` worked for my purposes, and https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_format was helpful.